# terraform azurerm download and run powershell scripts

Tags: windows, azure, terraform, azure-rm

I was looking at the best approach to do download this powershell script and apply it to my windows VM : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

what is the best approach ? extension ? Local-exec ?

thanks.

**EDIT :** There is this topic here that is explainging how to do it via customer script : [Defining Azure VM CustomScriptExtension in Terraform (Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text' with name '', namespace ''. \".")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310382/defining-azure-vm-customscriptextension-in-terraform-expecting-state-element) . My question to know what is the best based on given uses-cases.

Comment: Are you working with `azurerm_virtual_machine` or `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine`?

Comment: I use : azurerm_virtual_machine